# ASP.net Create a Torrent from File

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, bittorrent

Our current software updates are hosted on our server.

We'd like to offer Torrents as an alternative download option from our server.  When new releases are published it should offer people better download speeds if people seed it.

I've figured out everything except how to create a Torrent file automatically (we'd rather not have to create it manually each time).

Does anyone know how we can create a torrent file from a specified exe file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[MonoTorrent](http://www.monotorrent.com/) seems like it might be of help. I've previously compiled and run it under .net, so no worries there.

[This](http://www.monotorrent.com/wiki/monotorrent/Creating_Torrents) looks like the relevant wiki page.

As usual, it's probably best to check [license](https://github.com/mono/monotorrent/blob/master/src/LICENSE) compatibility before integrating with your product, but it looks quite permissive.

Of course, you'll need to host the torrent to ensure at least a single seed!